# How to run this MySQL query in codeigniter using active record pattern

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I am using ci and using its active record pattern to access database. I want to update table using statement like

```
UPDATE employee_barcode set `count` = `count` + 1
where barcode_id = 2
```

I tried using update statement like this

```
$data = array(
            'count' => 'count' + 1,
        );

$this->db->where('barcode_id', 2);
$this->db->update('employee_barcode', $data);
```

But the result was wrong.

How can i do so?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because `$this->db->update` can't get the value of `count`, and therefore can't add 1 to it. You should get the `count` value using `$this->db->select`, then proceed to update the value.

For example:

```
$this->db->where('barcode_id', 2);
$this->db->select('count');
$query = $this->db->get('employee_barcode');
$row = $query->row();
$this->db->where('barcode_id', 2);
$this->db->update('employee_barcode', array('count' => ($row->count + 1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$this->db->set('count', '`count+1`', FALSE)
$this->db->where('barcode_id', 2);
$this->db->update('employee_barcode');
```